# How do write .keycode event dependent on not holding down other keys

Tags: javascript, if-statement, event-handling, jquery-events, keycode

I've got a function on my web app that fires when any letter or number is pressed. This can get quite annoying for power users though when something like <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (OSX page refresh) is used.

Right now my js looks like:

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
   if(e.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
      // doing stuff
   }
});
```

How can I write my if statement so `.keycode` only works if any other key isn't being held down?

Answer (score 0):

Success!

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
      if (!e.metaKey) {
        if(e.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 || e.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
            // doing stuff
        }
  }
}
```

See it in action here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/xbVoxY